# Customize setter property C# 10

Tags: c#, c#-10.0

I am using C# 10 and want to convert any value that bind to `Operator` to lowercase

```
public class Rule
 {
    public string Operator { get; set; }
 }
```

I can't do creating another property and set the value.

```
private string _Operator ;
public string Operator 
{
  get            
  {
    return _Operator ;
  }
  set             
  {
    _Operator = value.toLower();
  }
}
```

Is there any way to directly convert to lowercase whatever bind to  `public string Operator { get; set; }`

Comment: I don't think you can do that.

Comment: I think this question is too small. If you zoom out a bit and provide context we may find a solution.

Comment: "I can't do creating another property and set the value." why not?

Comment: _"I can't do creating another property and set the value."_ -  Just FYI `_Operator ` is not another property, it is a field.

Answer (score 1):

## A. Have a separate property

```
public string Operator { get; set; }

public string BetterOperator => Operator?.ToLower();
```

If you have an original class that you cannot fully control (e.g. auto-generated) I'd try with partial classes:

```
public partial class Rule
{
    public string Operator { get; set; }
}

public partial class Rule
{
    public string BetterOperator => Operator?.ToLower();
}
```

## B. Virtual

Another option could be making the property virtual and using a derived class:

(*I switched from classes to records just for a nice Console.WriteLine*)

```
public record Rule
{
    public virtual string? Operator { get; set; }
}

public record RuleExt : Rule
{
    public override string? Operator
    {
        get { return base.Operator; }
        set { base.Operator = value?.ToLower(); }
    }
}
```

Then the following:

```
var r = new RuleExt() { Operator = "Plus" };

Print(r);

static void Print(Rule r) => Console.WriteLine(r);
```

Will print:

```
RuleExt { Operator = plus }
```

Comment: _"Another option could be making the property virtual and using a derived class"_ - do not forget to emphasize that you switched from classes to records, cause otherwise your _"Will print:"_ statement will be false.